# Can't install steam on ubuntu, i'm on a chromebook

Tags: 14.04, steam, troubleshooting

I installed Ubuntu on my chromebook with

```
sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t kde
```

I thought that all was good in the world, but when I install steam from their website, run it through the Ubuntu software-center, and clicked on the `.deb` file it gives me:

```
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
```

And tells me to press return. Upon doing so I get an error message saying:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6".
```

Should I do a fresh install? I've tried it 4 times and they all resulted in the same error.

Comment: Dang it, your right. I'm running an arm (Specifically armv7l). Gaben, please get arm support!!! I suppose since only low end components use arm, this will never be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Chromebooks have ARM instruction set processors, but Steam only supports x86.

You can discover your system architecture with the terminal command `uname -m`.